# Error : I am new to C# programming and rying to get started using VSCODE as an text editor

Tags: c#, .net, oop

How do I solve this.

> Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in D:\c#, or pass the path to the project using --project

I have installed the .NET  SDK in C drive and trying to run the program saved in D drive. I am using Visual Studio Code. And just got started with C#. This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing called ".NET SDK", as it should be either .NET Core SDK, or .NET Framework SDK (VSCode does not support the latter very well). And you must have a valid project file recognized by VSCode before anything else, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp#_roslyn-and-omnisharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get started from scratch. Follow these steps:

1. Open your Visual Studio Code and press **Ctrl + `**. This will open your Console.
2. Within your console, you will see a default path as C:\Users\ (something like this). Now write this command:  **mkdir CSharp.**
   This will create a folder named CSharp inside your C:\Users folder.
3. Next, type this command: cd CSharp. This is required to jump to the folder you just created in step 2.
4. In this step, write **dotnet new console**. This is the command to create a basic console application. Make sure you have installed .NET CLI on your system.
5. Write **dotnet run**. This will run your console application.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are missing a parenthesis } from the end of your code file.

Secondly, you didn't mention how you created this code file, but the error message suggests that you have simply added a new .cs file to a folder. Visual Studio Code doesn't work that way, and requires a [project file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) to tell the compiler what to do with your code.

You *can* also [run the C# compiler directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) but given that you have Visual Studio Code and want to use it to manage your projects, the first option of using the project file as it is designed to do would probably be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly there's a lot of missing information in your question, here what I suggest:

Go to a folder of your choice in the cmd run:

(Considering that you installed .net core cli)

dotnet new console.

Open the folder with VScode, run the project.